# Partial load of iframe - looking for solution

Tags: iframe

Link to website:  http://tx-realtor.us/AllenTexasHomesForSale.htm

Code used: Head

```js
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
  html body {width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;overflow: hidden;font-family: 
  arial;font-size: 10px;color: #6e6e6e;background-color: #000;} #preview-frame {width: 
  100%;background-color: #fff;}</style>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     //function to fix height of iframe!
     var calcHeight = function() {
       //var headerDimensions = 0; //$('#header-bar').height();
       $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height());
     }
     
     $(document).ready(function() {
       calcHeight();
       /*$('#header-bar a.close').mouseover(function() {
         $('#header-bar a.close').addClass('activated');
       }).mouseout(function() {
         $('#header-bar a.close').removeClass('activated');
       });*/
     }); 
     
     $(window).resize(function() {
       calcHeight();
     }).load(function() {
       calcHeight();
     });
  </script>
```

Code used: Body

```js
<iframe id="preview-frame" src="https://www.davemeneo.dallasareahomelistings.com/search? 
   acl_city=Allen%2C+TX&minbeds=0&minbaths=0&maxprice=880000&page=1&type=grid" name="preview-frame"
        frameBorder="0" noresize="noresize" style="height: 902px;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: getting the frame to load completely